# Var arg list in main

Tags: c, c99, variadic-functions

I want to use my program like this:

```
./program -I /usr/include/ /usr/bin/ /usr/local/include/ ...
```

Where the switch can go on and on like in a var args list. How could I do that in C99? Preferably get a something like `char **args_list` or `char *args_list[]` that contains all of the things like `/usr/include` and `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Can't you do this with `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`?

Comment: No worries. @linuxuser27's answer below is what you need.

Comment: I have just one more quick question. Check the update!

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of mixing two together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of running the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Executed by `program -I /usr/include/ /usr/bin/ /usr/local/include/`

Output:

```
-I
/usr/include/
/usr/bin/
/usr/local/include/
```

Note that in the code example the initial index is `1`.  This is because the first pointer in the `argv` variable is the name of the program.  In this case it would be `program`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just have one more quick question. Check the update!

Answer (score 0):

Your program in the update is probably segfaulting because you're running off the end of the array:

```
    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
```

there's no guarantee there is an `argv[2]`.

(It may be null if argc==2, but I think not all printfs cope with that.)